# Benefit of Binding a GridView in Page_PreRender vs Page_Load?

Tags: asp.net

Assume I have an asp:GridView with some customer information.  On that page I also have a button which allows me to add a new user to the GridView.  When I add the click the user, I databind the gridview again in the button click.  Correct me if I am wrong, but if the asp.net lifecycle or at least part of it is in the following order:

page_load
Hookup event handlers such as my button click
page_preRender

Does this mean that if I put the databinding for the gridview in preRender, that is the only place I need to worry about calling it.  I can remove it from the button click.  This is what I think, but I am not sure if my thinking is correct, so I would like some more insight as to the benefit of putting code in PreRender as opposed to PageLoad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By PreRender, you assume that most logic in the page that would affect the binding result has been completed (usually in `Page_Load`, but anywhere earlier really).

Controls in the .Net framework by default do their binding in the PreRender event *(makes sense, bind to the datasource at the last possible moment...could be that you changed the data 400 times earlier in the lifecycle)*.  [Here's the full layout of the 2.0 lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) for reference.

> **PreRender** - Before this event occurs:
>
> - The Page object calls EnsureChildControls for each control and for the page.
> - Each data bound control whose DataSourceID property is set calls its DataBind method. For more information, see Data Binding Events for Data-Bound Controls later in this topic.
>
> The PreRender event occurs for each control on the page. Use the event to make final changes to the contents of the page or its controls.

Comment: One thing to note though is that if you are doing anything funky with the control being bound, i.e. getting the selected rows from a grid in the onclick handler for a button, then you may have to bind the grid earlier (during the Page OnLoad). For instance, when doing stuff with a DevExpress grid, we always have to bind it in the Page_Load for some of the grid events to work correctly.